# How to split an input sequence according to the input number given

Tags: clojure

I'm writing a clojure function like:

```
(defn area [n locs]
  (let [a1 (first locs)]
    (vrp (rest locs))))
```

I basically want to input like: `(area 3 '([1 2] [3 5] [3 1] [4 2]))` But when I do that it gives me an error saying `Wrong number of args (1) passed`. But I'm passing two arguments.

What I actually want to do with this function is that whatever value of n is inputted (say 3 is inputted), then a1 should store [1 2], a2 should store [3 5], a3 should store ([3 1] [4 2]). What should I add in the function to get that?

Comment: what does vrp do? could you include it's defn?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt *vrp* no doubt stands for [*Vehicle Routing Problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem). I suspect that `n` is the number of vehicles available and `locs` is the list of places to be visited, of which the first `n` are the locations of the respective vehicle depots. Probably easier to deal with as `(defn area [vehicle-locs visit-locs])`.

Answer (score 0):

clojue's build in `split-at` function is very close to solving this. It splits a sequence "at" a given point. So if we first split the data apart and then wrap the second half in a list and concatenate it back together again it should solve this problem:

```
user> (let [[start & end] (split-at 2 sample-data)] 
        (concat start end))
([1 2] [3 5] ([3 1] [4 2]))
```

the `&` before end in let causes the last item to be rolled up in a list. It's equivalent to:

```
user> (let [[start end] (split-at 2 sample-data)]
        (concat start (list end)))
([1 2] [3 5] ([3 1] [4 2]))
```

If I recklessly assume you have some function called vrp that needs data in this form then you could finish your function with something like this:

```
(defn area [n locs]
  (let [[start end] (split-at (dec n) sample-data)
        a (concat start (list end))]
    (apply vrp a)))
```

Though please forgive me to making wild guesses as to the nature of vrp, I could be totally off base here.